# В чем ошибка? неверный счетчик

Tags: c++, visual-c++, while

```
setlocale(0,"");
    int i=1;
    int n;
    int k=0;

    cout<<"Введите предел: ";
    cin>>n;

    while(i<=n)
    {
        i++;
        k+=i;
    }

    cout<<"Сумма всех чисел = "<<k<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(i<=n)
{
    k+=i++;
}
```

Так будет лучше. А то вы начинаете суммировать с двойки...

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, зачем тут вообще `while`, вроде код считает сумму арифметической прогрессии, что можно сделать за одно действие:

```
k = ((1 + n) * n) / 2;
```

Comment: Ну, может, с дидактическими целями :) - студенту выбирать не приходится...